# C++ Builder TArray<System.Byte> not compiling

Tags: udp, vcl, indy, c++builder-xe

I'm trying to include the `idUDPServer` component (Indy component) in a C++ Builder XE project and when I try to include the `onUDPRead` event (manually linking it to the component because of a known bug in C++ Builder XE).

All articles I have read so far solves this problem by manually assign the event function to the component.

In my case I can't compile because it can't recognize the `TArray<System.Byte>` parameter.
I have tried to include the `<System.hpp>` but it doesn't help.

Is there anyone that has managed to solve this issue with `TArray`?

Function declaration:

```
void __fastcall UDPServerUDPRead(TIdUDPListenerThread *AThread, TArray<System.Byte> AData, TIdSocketHandle *ABinding);
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `TArray<System.Byte>` is Delphi syntax.  The C++ equivilent is `TArray<System::Byte>`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB. Well `TArray<System.Byte>` is what C++ Builder XE is generating when I double click the `OnUDPRead event` (beside the other error "`Incorrect method declaration in class...`". If that is correct code or not is hard to know with the mix of non C++ standard and Delphi code in the bottom.

Comment: Anyway it doesn't compile if I change to `TArray<System::Byte>`. I get the `E2293 ) expected` after `TArray` meaning it can't find the `TArray` declaration. I also included the `#define <Generics.Collections.hpp>` (because it was not defined in `system.hpp` as the documentation stated) to get the `TArray` declaration, with the same E2293 error.

Comment: `TBytes` (and `TIdBytes`) is based on the `TArray<T>` type that is declared in `System.pas`, not the `TArray<T>` class that is declared in `Generics.Collections.pas`. In C++, `TBytes` is declared in `System.SysUtils.hpp` as a typedef for `DynamicArray<System::Byte>`, as `TArray` is not exposed directly in C++ (but if it were, it would be known as `TArray__1`, as is commented in various places where `DynamicArray<Byte>` is used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I solved it.

I remembered that I had successfully upgraded an earlier project using the `idUDPServer` control without any problem. So why did that code compile and not this new one?

After some research I found that apparently Delphi (I know, it's weird. C++ Builder is written partly in Delphi) solves all types to its base form and there is an issue with the `TArray<System.Data>` type.

I copied the declaration from the converted project:

```
void __fastcall UDPServerUDPRead(TIdUDPListenerThread *AThread, TIdBytes AData, TIdSocketHandle *ABinding);
```

As you can see the `TArray<System.Data>` is replaced with `TIdBytes`. It compiles without any warnings or Errors. You still have to assign the event function manually although (in the Create Event).

```
UDPServer->OnUDPRead = &UDPServerUDPRead;
```

*** EDIT ***
Updated code `TBytes` to `TIdBytes` as Remy Lebeau - TeamB corrected me.

Comment: When assigning the event handler manually, you should use the type that Indy is actually expecting, which is `TIdBytes`, not `TBytes`.  `TBytes` keeps the compiler happy, but `TIdBytes` is what Indy is actually coded to use.

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau - TeamB. Okay, I can't argue with you there ;) I would have seen it if I had checked the Indy documentation (it's still in Delphi even if I have C++ Builder). It compiled fine with `TIdBytes` instead of `TBytes`. Although `TBytes` is used on .NET platforms according to the indy documentation.

Comment: `TBytes` is also available in newer Delphi versions. It is just an alias for `array of Byte`, aka `DynamicArray<Byte>` in C++.